# Simple effect of a variable at different levels of a continuous variable in linear mixed model

Tags: python, statsmodels, continuous

I have variable x which is continuous, and
variable y which is also continuous and
I have variable z (continuous) as the dependent variable.
Participants are the random effect variable and
I should do linear mixed effect model.

I want to test the simple effect of variable x at different levels of variable y. I am using Python statsmodels. But I do not know how to proceed as usually in the examples variable y is categorical. How would you progress through such analysis?

Thank you,

Comment: errr... bin your y variables? like make it discrete into y - low, y -medium, y - high, hey this is incredibly vague ....

Comment: Yes, I binned them by using median and divided them into 2. However, I still think/hope that there might be a better option out there.

Comment: you can use what is called an interaction term, https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-can-i-explain-a-continuous-by-continuous-interaction-stata-12/